# Outlook unified inbox work around using categoreis?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use office 365, and figured out the way in the desktop version (by search) to have a sort of "unified inbox".  Now I'd like to see visually which account the email is from.  I'd like to use categories for this, (was thinking rule to specific category, etc.) but we already use categories for something else.

Any workaround to possibly create a second set of categories, or even an icon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we just no need categories. Adding a new "To" column in the search results view like below can make things more easier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem with that is they both show up as my name.

Comment: Sorry for the delay here. Guess you might configure the same display name for different email account in your Outlook, right? Try different display names might be able to make this method helpful. By the way, as I know, we can not create a second set of categories in Outlook. If necessary, you may could try some third-party add-ins to see if it could help.

Comment: Thank you Jeff.  So far, right now, I have them sort of labeled and it seems to be working.  I wanted to try eM Client but ran into technical issues, and the support was nil.  Even tried Mailbird, but signatures don't work well.  Probably just need to keep looking.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to see that you have found labeled as a workaround. You are welcome. Best wishes.